# Yii2 Validator Exist

Tags: yii2

Estoy intentando validar un campo de un formulario dinámico.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el campo color_proveedor exista en otra tabla para determinado id, en este caso para el id 123456 que se ve en el combo de arriba.
Si yo tuviese por ejemplo la tabla2 con el id 123456 y con los codigos de colores 001 y 002, cualquier otro que ingrese en el formulario de la imagen me de error. Estuve intentando utilizar el validador exist pero no termino de entender y no se si es posible hacer algo asi con el validador o hacer algo personalizado. Gracias

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'cod_color_int','tela' ,'descripcion', 'nom_proveedor', 'tela_proveedor', 'color_proveedor', 'color_predominante', 'temporada'], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['id_tela'], 'string', 'max' => 7],
        [['tela'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
        [['cod_color_int', 'temporada'], 'string', 'max' => 3],
        [['descripcion'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['nom_proveedor', 'color_proveedor'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['tela_proveedor', 'color_predominante'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['proceso'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['temporada'], 'string', 'max' => 3],
        [['color_proveedor'], 'exist', 'targetClass' => TelasProvDet::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['color_proveedor' => 'cod_color'],'allowArray' => true], // Se que esta mal pero estuve probando cosas similares.
        [['id_tela'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Telas::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_tela' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

Ahi lo que busco es que el campo color_proveedor exista en la tabla TelasProvDet donde se llama cod_color para un determinado id

```
public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new Telas();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}


<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    [
        'id' => $model->formName(),
        'enableClientValidation' => true, 
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(['telas/validation']), 
        'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'd-none']],
        'formConfig' => ['showLabels'=>false],
        'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'alert alert-danger',
    ]
); ?>

<div class="form-group mt-3 card-grid p-3">
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-container']); ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    [
        'id' => $model->formName(),
        'enableClientValidation' => true, 
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(['telas/validation']), 
        'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'd-none']],
        'formConfig' => ['showLabels'=>false],
        'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'alert alert-danger',
    ]
); ?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?> 
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
    'limit' => 999, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 0, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.clonar', // css class
    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
    'model' => $modelsTelasColores[0],
    'formId' => $model->formName(),
    'formFields' => [
        'cod_color_int',
        'descripcion',
        'color_proveedor',
        'color_predominante'
    ],
]); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?= 
            $form->field($model, "temporada")->widget(Select2::classname(), 
                [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map($getTemporadas,'id','descripcion'),
                'language' => 'es',
                'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Temporada'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                ],
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    'change' => "function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#telas-id').focus().select()
                        }, 1);

                    }"
                ]
            ]);
        ?>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput(['maxlength' => 4, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Tela'])?>           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'descripcion')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción', 'readonly' => true, 'tabindex' => '1']) ?>           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'composicion')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Composición', 'readonly' => true, 'tabindex' => '1']) ?>           
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?= 
            $form->field($model, 'nom_proveedor')->widget(Select2::classname(), 
                [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map($getProveedores,'nom_proveedor','nom_proveedor'),
                'language' => 'es',
                'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleccione un proveedor', 'disabled' => $model->isNewRecord ? true : false],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                ],  
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    'change' => "function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#telas-id_telaprovcab').select2('focus')
                        }, 1);       
                    }"
                ]                          
            ]);
        ?>      

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <?=                 
            $form->field($model, 'id_telaprovcab')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
                'select2Options'=>['pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true]],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                    'depends'=>['telas-nom_proveedor'],
                    'initialize' => true,
                    'params'=> ['input-type-1'],
                    'url' => Url::to(['proveedor-telas']),
                    'loadingText' => 'Cargando Telas...',
                    'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una Tela',
                ],
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    'change' => "function(){
                        $.post('".Url::to(['colores'])."', {id : $(this).val()}, function(result){
                            data = JSON.parse(result)
                            $('.container-items').html('')
                            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                                $('button[name=new]').click();    
                                index = $('.panel-default').length - 1
                                $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_proveedor').val(value.cod_color)
                                $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_proveedor').prop('readonly',true)
                                $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_predominante').val(value.color_predominante).trigger('change')
                                $('#telas-descripcion').val(value.tela_proveedor)
                                $('#telas-composicion').val(value.composicion)  
                                if(value.tipo == 'APTA'){
                                    $('#telascolores-'+index+'-descripcion').val($('#telas-descripcion').val())
                                }else{
                                    $('#telascolores-'+index+'-descripcion').val(value.descripcion)
                                }
                                $('#tipo').val(value.tipo)
                                var cant = $('.panel-default').length
                                $('#cant').val(cant);
                            });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('#telascolores-0-cod_color_int').focus().select()
                            }, 1);                               
                        });
                    }"
                ]

            ]);
        ?>           
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 d-none">
        <button type="button" title="Agregar Fila" style="font-size: 0.8rem !important" class='add-item btn btn-success p-2 hidden-sm-down' name='new' tabindex="1"><i class="fa fa-plus text-center "></i></button> 
    </div>
</div>  
<?php echo Html::hiddenInput('input-type-1',$model->id_telaprovcab,['id'=>'input-type-1']); ?>
<?php echo Html::hiddenInput('tipo',$model->tipo,['id'=>'tipo']);?>
<?php echo Html::hiddenInput('cant',count($modelsTelasColores),['id'=>'cant']);?>
<hr>    

<div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
<?php foreach ($modelsTelasColores as $i => $modelTelasColores): ?>
    <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->                   
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
                // necessary for update action.
                if (! $modelTelasColores->isNewRecord) {
                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelTelasColores, "[{$i}]id");
                }
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?= $form->field($modelTelasColores, "[{$i}]cod_color_int",[
                        'addon' => ['prepend' => ['content'=>'Color']]
                    ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Cod. Color']) ?>          
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelTelasColores, "[{$i}]descripcion")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción']) ?>          
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?= $form->field($modelTelasColores, "[{$i}]color_proveedor")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Color proveedor', 'readonly' => true, 'tabindex' => '1']) ?>          
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-8">
                    <?= 
                        $form->field($modelTelasColores, "[{$i}]color_predominante")->widget(Select2::classname(), 
                            [
                            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(ColoresWeb::find()->all(),'descripcion','descripcion'),
                            'language' => 'es',
                            'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Color predominante'],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                            ],           
                        ]);
                    ?>      

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-4">
                    <button type="button" title="Clonar" style="font-size: 0.8rem !important" class='add-item btn btn-warning p-2 clonar'><i class="fa fa-clone text-center"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" title="Eliminar" style="font-size: 0.8rem !important" class='remove-item btn btn-danger p-2' tabindex= '1'><i class='fa fa-trash text-center'></i></button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>                    
<?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>

<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- BOTON GUARDAR AJAX  -->
        <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
            'label' => 'Guardar',
            'useWithActiveForm' => $model->formName(),
            'ajaxOptions' => [
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'create' : Url::to(['update', 'id' => $model->temporada.$model->id]),
                'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){                      

                }')
            ],
            'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit'],
            'icon' => 'fas fa-save'
            ]);
        AjaxSubmitButton::end(); ?>   
        <?= Html::a("<i class='fas fa-ban text-center'></i> Cancelar", ['cancelar'], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) ?>           

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?> 
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    $this->registerJs("   
            if( $('#telas-temporada').val() !== '' && $('#telas-nom_proveedor').prop('disabled') == false){
                $('#telas-id').focus().select()                
            }
            $('#telas-id').on('keyup',function(e){
                if(e.target.value.length==4){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '".Url::to(['buscar-tela'])."',
                        data: {id : $('#telas-temporada').val()+$(this).val() },
                        success: function(result) {
                            if(!result){
                                $('#telas-nom_proveedor').prop('disabled',false) 
                                $('#telas-nom_proveedor').focus() 
                            }
                        },
                    })
                }
            }); 

            $('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function(e, item) {                
                if($('.panel-default').length <= $('#cant').val() ){
                    index = $('.panel-default').length -1           
                }else{
                    index = $('.panel-default').length -1       
                    $('#telascolores-'+index+'-descripcion').val($('#telas-descripcion').val())  
                    if($('#tipo').val() == 'APTA'){
                        $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_proveedor').val($('#telascolores-'+(index-1)+'-color_proveedor').val())      
                        $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_proveedor').prop('readonly',true)                     
                    }else{
                        $('#telascolores-'+index+'-color_proveedor').prop('readonly',false)
                    }                       
                } 
            })       
        "
        , \yii\web\View::POS_END);
 ?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Lo estás haciendo con los models de yii2?, pon los rules de ese modelo

Comment: Sii, ahi lo edite. Lo provee de varias formas y no logro ni siquiera que me de error cuando no exista.

Comment: pon tu controller y tu vista también

Comment: Yo estoy compartiendo dos formularios en la misma vista y un mismo controlador. y en el controlador solo una validacion, que es la del model de Telas, no TelasColores, no se como hacer la de los dos modelos juntos. Las reglas del principio son del modelo TelasColores

Comment: Tu error muy porbablemente esté en el `telasValidation` pega el actionValidation y su código

Comment: No te entendi bien, yo ahi puse el codigo de actionValidation, no tengo otra validacion en ese controlador, y en ese controlador hago las acciones para los dos formularios. Lo unico que esta separado son los modelos. Telas y TelasColores

Comment: pon todo el view de tu form completo para tener una mejor vista

Comment: Ahi lo puse. Para dejar en claro como es. Tengo dos modelos Telas y TelasColores. Tengo un solo controlador para ambos modelos y dos formularios en la misma vista. La validacion la quiero hacer en el modelo TelasColores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es validar únicamente TelasColores

```
public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new TelasColores(); //Aquí ya validas telas colores
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

Si lo que quieres es validar ambos entonces crea un nuevo modelo y  valida ambos

```
public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new Telas();
    $model2 = new TelasColores();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model) && ActiveForm::validate($model2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm perfecto y en cuanto a la regla de validación como se haria para validar lo que necesitó? Por lo menos la validación que escribí esta bien echa? Me refiero a la que uso el exist

Comment: En teoría sí, pero el allowArray me parece innecesario, para qué lo pusiste?

Comment: Sinceramente para probar algo distinto jaja, no se bien en que casos se usa. Lo que ahí falta que no se como agregar es que todo eso se cumpla pero para un id en especial, osea que exista en esa tabla para esa columna pero para un cierto id, no para toda la tabla, no se si me explico

Comment: Pude lograrlo usando el código que puse arriba, como se puede ver solo valida un modelo, aunque de todas maneras al otro lo valida no se porq. lo que necesito es adherir un filtro where para que la validacion se haga para un id especifico y queria saber como hacer para validar que yo no pueda ingresar uno igual, por ejemplo en la imagen me deberia tirar error al escribir 001 porq ya esta en el primer campo.